# Using ng-switch for null or empty values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a variable like $rootScope.user = {name:"abc",password:"asd"}. I am assigning this to rootscope on a service response [dynamically creating a rootscope variable]. Now how to implement ng-switch to check whether it has some value [i.e. not null or not undefined].

```
<section  ng-switch on="user">
      <span ng-switch-when="null">{{user.name}}</span>
      <span ng-switch-default>Hello</span>
 </section>`
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to inject the `$rootScope` into your controller. Then you can store user object to `$rootScope` as

```
$rootScope.user = {
    name: "abc",
    password: "asd"
}
```

To retrieve the user object from `$rootScope`, Write the following function in your controller

```
$scope.getUserNameFromRootScope : function(){
  return $rootScope.user.name;
}
```

Now you can call this function in your selection element

```
<section  ng-switch on="getUserFromRootScope()">
  <span ng-switch-when="abc">{{user.name}}</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="null">The name is empty</span>
  <span ng-switch-default>Hello</span>
</section>
```